# How to use the modulus to calculate the rate?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2012, module

Within my code I have to calculate the Rate fee with the distance.

The shipping cost is obtained by multiplying the 'shipping rate' with the 'number of 500 mile segments'. Shipping rate is based on the weight of the package. Number of 500 mile segments needs to be calculated based on the distance entered by the user since the rate is not pro rated.

for example: The weight of the package is 5.6  so the Rate will be $2.00 because the weight is under 10 pounds. the Distance is 1200 miles. (500 modulus 1200 equals three ) so 3 * 2.00 should get me 6.00 for a final result.

How can I use or express in code the modulus operator to find my answer?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h>                                                             


int main() {

    double Weight, rate;


    printf("Enter the Weight of your package:\n");

    scanf_s("%lf", &Weight);

    printf("Your Weight is: %.2lf\n", Weight);



    if (Weight <= 10)
        rate = 2.00;                   

    else
        if (Weight <= 50)
            rate = 4.50;                     

    printf("so your rate will be: %.2lf\n", rate);

    int Distance=0, result;

    printf("Now please enter the Distance: ");

scanf_s("%d", &Distance);                                           

    if (Distance >= 500)          
        result = Distance % 500 * rate ;

    printf("your Distance fee is: %d", result);






    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must 
include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful 
to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: From your description, the rate increases every 500 miles.  So if, as in your example, the distance is 1200 miles the rate is 3*(2.00).  Where in your code do you calculate the number of times 500 divides the distance?  and where to multiply the base rate by the above quotient?

Comment: What happens if `Weight` is larger than 50?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi If it is larger than 50 then the system will tell the user that it only calculates weight lower than 50.

Comment: @thurizas Within my code the calculations are done after the user inputs the distance amount. The calculation is done after 'if (Distance >=500)' where it says 'result= Distance% 500' then I would multiply by the rate that was given.  In this case $2.00.  I am very new to programming so please let me know if my explanation does not make sense

Comment: It is not a modulo operation.  int Segments = (Distance + 499) / 500;

Comment: @Don '%' is the modulo operator, it returns the remainder after integer division, so assuming Distance is 1200, the line `result=Distance%500` will assign 200 (the remainder in 1200 / 500) to result.  Remember, that integer division, i.e. 1200/500, will truncate the result dropping all fractions, so `1200/500` will equal 2 (as 2*500 = 1000) and `1200%500` will return 200.  Recall that 1200 can be written as `1200 = 2*500 + 200`.  What you may be interested in is the ceiling function, i.e. `ceil(x)`, but you will need to work with floating point numbers not integers.

Comment: Thank you! @Hans Passant and  This has helped me a lot! i manage to get the build to work accordingly, all I have to do is get the system to let the user know that weight can only be calculated  under 50 pounds. Thank you for helping me I am slowly learning programming.

Comment: Thank you @thurizas ! I have not yet learned about the ceiling function but i will do some research on it. I hope to one day to know as much as you do in programming. Thanks again.